# spring rest @requestbody get child object

Tags: json, spring, rest

I has a problem：There will be three child class Student,Teacher,Parent.

```
public class Person implements Serializable{

private String name;

private String address;}
```

Student:

```
public class Student extends Person {

private String cardNo;
```

}

spring rest :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/create")
@ResponseBody
public CemeteryRestResponse<Boolean> create(
        @RequestBody Person person) throws Exception {.....}
```

I want to use the one rest method to create these three role.
but in client post Student as JSON it throws a Exception :

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "cardNo"
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: If you only want the name and address fields and don't care about the cardNo field, add this Jackson annotation to the `Person` class: `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

Comment: Thanks.but there will be three child class Student,Teacher,Parent.I want to use the one rest method to create these three role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jackson library supports [polymorphic type handling](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) which is what it appears you are after.  The specific annotation you should be looking for is the [`@JsonTypeInfo`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonTypeInfo.html) annotation, and you should apply it to the base class (the `Person` class).

This feature was added in version 1.5.

Comment: thanks!
I apply @JSONTypeInfo to the base class like this:
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
public class Person implements Serializable

but it throws new Exception :org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property '@class'